# Looking to add new color options to a current product. (Question from someone new to Magento 2.4) Can anyone provide step-by-step directions?

Tags: color-swatches

[image]

Looking to add extra color swatches here. I'm pretty new to Magento 2.4 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Please check blow links** to add new color option for the product. https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-colors/ https://zemez.io/support/magento/how-to/magento-2-add-color-swatches/ https://bsscommerce.com/blog/2-easy-steps-to-add-color-swatch-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to add an option to every attributes in Magento.

## 1. Find your attribute

You can find your product attribute here : **Store > Attributes > Product**

This will lead you to a list of every product attribute.

Search for 'color' in attribute code column
[image: Go to product attribute list]

## 2. Edit your product attribute

You can edit your product attribute by clicking on it

On Your product attribute, look for the list of each value you can have. here on sample data 'Manage Swatch'

[image: Add option to product attribute]

Don't forget to click on this tiny icon to add your color.

Add a label to it, then you can save your attribute.

## 3. Edit your configurable product

Reach your configurable product to edit it.

On configuration tab click 'Edit configuration'

[image]

On step 2, select the colors you want to add to the product
[image]

On step 4, Magento give you a summary of product taht will be created
[image]

Click 'Generate product' and configure the new product by adding image, price, quantity, weight...

You can save your product and check on your storefront

## 4. Verify

Verify on storefront the new added color
[image]

**Hope this helped you. If you need a programmaticaly way, let me know**